# What does the code do?

Tags: disassembly, x86

[Challenge #64](https://challenges.re/64/)

What does this code do?

An array of `array[x][y]` form is accessed here. Try to determine the dimensions of the array, at least partially, by finding y.

```
_array$ = 8
_x$ = 12
_y$ = 16
_f  PROC
    mov eax, DWORD PTR _x$[esp-4]
    mov edx, DWORD PTR _y$[esp-4]
    mov ecx, eax
    shl ecx, 4
    sub ecx, eax
    lea eax, DWORD PTR [edx+ecx*8]
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR _array$[esp-4]
    fld QWORD PTR [ecx+eax*8]
    ret 0
_f  ENDP
```

At first I think there is a mistake in the question. Because I only see three variables here, one for array address, the one x and one y, so I assume it's actually a 2d array of double, not a 3d as in *"An array of `array[x][y]`"*.

Then I was stuck because eventually the program loads `array[8y+192x]`, and x and y can be anything.

So I figured this must be a 3d array of double, with the third dimension given. I still couldn't figure it out so I tried to write my own program and use Godbolt to give me assembly. After a few trials I got something pretty close to the original program:

[Something close](https://godbolt.org/z/bT7bq8exa)

However I'm still having difficulty to match my program with the original question. I think I'm pretty close but how do I proceed from here? I have a hunch that y is also 24 in the original question, but not 100% sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is somewhat of a symbolic simplification. If you execute code from start of the procedure, then just before ret these are the relevant changes to the state of the program - ignoring registers

```
float_st0          = @64[array + (y + x * 0x78) * 0x8]
float_stack_ptr    = float_stack_ptr + 0x1
```

where `st0` has been loaded with a 64bit value from a location.

```
array + (y + x * 0x78) * 0x8
```

In a 1D array the way you access any index is

```
array + index * sizeof(member)
```

The size of the array member is 8 `sizeof(double)` here so the index is

```
y + x * 0x78
```

2D arrays are laid out linearly in memory. Accessing second dimension requires the size of first dimension to be known -

[image]

In the above example to access `array[1][2]` we need to access it like

```
array + sizeof(int) * (2 + 1 * 3)
```

In the op `x` is getting multiplied by 0x78 - so the size of the `y` dimension is 0x78 members.

Additionally I could replicate the problem code to an extent [here](https://godbolt.org/z/8n74safKd)

With this code and x86 MSVC v19.0, optimization flag /Ox

```
double load(double array[][0x78], int x, int y) {
    return array[x][y];
}
```

we get

```
_array$ = 8                                   ; size = 4
_x$ = 12                                                ; size = 4
_y$ = 16                                                ; size = 4
_load   PROC
        mov     ecx, DWORD PTR _x$[esp-4]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR _y$[esp-4]
        shl     ecx, 4
        sub     ecx, DWORD PTR _x$[esp-4]
        lea     ecx, DWORD PTR [eax+ecx*8]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR _array$[esp-4]
        fld     QWORD PTR [eax+ecx*8]
        ret     0
_load   ENDP
```

PS : I ran this through a miasm based simplification - code [here](https://gist.github.com/sudhackar/6590295409de25599cb409b3af6ebf9b)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll read through and take notes. BTW also thanks for introducing the miasm tool, I had no idea it exists.

Comment: @NicholasHumphrey If this solves the question you asked, you can accept it. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Done! Thanks man